# -static-libstdc++ works on g++ but not on pure gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, mingw32

For the reference I'm using MinGW (GCC 5.3). When compiling a file with

`g++ file.cc -static-libstdc++`

it statically links the C++ standard lib (`libstdc++`) and produces a 1.9MB executable.

However running

`gcc -lstdc++ -static-libstdc++ file.cc`

it still dynamically links to `libstdc++-6.dll` and produces a 34KB executable.

Why does `-static-libstdc++` only work with `g++` but not with pure `gcc`?

Comment: `-static-libstdc++` is a C++ flag ... and by writing `gcc` you specified linking a C program

Comment: But aren't `gcc` and `g++` the same thing? AFAIK the only major difference is that `g++` automatically links the standard library, unlike `gcc` where I have to pass `-lstdc++`. I can compile c++ code with `gcc`.

Comment: I think this question demonstrates that they are not ... (when it comes to linking)

Comment: I don't see why this is a problem. Just use `g++` for C++ code.

Comment: I was just interested in how they are different and why one accepts a specific flag and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [GCC manual, Link Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) says:

> -static-libstdc++
>
> When the g++ program is used to link a C++ program, it normally automatically links 
>   against libstdc++. If libstdc++ is available as a shared library, and the -static
>   option is not used, then this links against the shared version of libstdc++. 
>   That is normally fine. However, it is sometimes useful to freeze the version of
>   libstdc++ used by the program without going all the way to a fully static link. 
>   The -static-libstdc++ option directs the g++ driver to link libstdc++ statically, 
>   without necessarily linking other libraries statically.

This makes clear that the option `-static-libstdc++` is meaningful only to
the `g++` compiler driver, not `gcc` or any other.

On the other hand the option `-l<name>` is meaningful and means the same thing
to all GCC compiler drivers. On that basis it is not surprising that:

```
gcc file.cc -lstdc++ -static-libstdc++
```

has the same meaning as:

```
gcc file.cc -lstdc++
```

*However*, that observation does not truly illuminate why the first of those
commandlines dynamically links `libstdc++`:-

`-static-libstdc++` is meaningful only to `g++` because only `g++` links
`libstdc++` automatically. So it is only for `g++` that the question arises
whether the automatically linked `libstdc++` will be the dynamic version
or the static version. The dynamic version is the default: `-static-libstdc++`
insists on the static version.

The *automatic linking of* `libstdc++` by `g++` means this: `g++` silently
appends `-lstdc++` to whatever linkage options *you* specify (along with
quite a lot of other boiler-plate for a C++ linkage). You can reveal all
the boilerplate by requesting verbose linkage (`g++ ... -Wl,-v ...`).

By itself, the appended `-lstdc++` will cause the linker to link the dynamic version
of `libstdc++`, per its default behaviour. The only difference made by
`-static-libstdc++` is that in the place where `-lstdc++` would otherwise
be silently passed to the linker, the options:

```
-Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic
```

are silently passed to it instead. These tell the linker:

- `-Bstatic`: Do not link dynamic libraries until further notice
- `-lstdc++`: Link `libstdc++`
- `-Bdynamic`: Link dynamic libraries until further notice.

You see how that works to secure the static linkage of `libstdc++` without
out side-effects on the linkage of any other library.

But you can also see that the automatic linkage of `libstdc++`, whether
dynamically or statically, *has no retroactive effect on the linkage
of any libraries you have specified yourself*.

Hence, if your linkage already includes `-lstdc++` before any boiler-plate
options are silently appended by the compiler driver, then `libstdc++` will be linked
in just the same way as any `-l<name>` at that position in the linkage
sequence. And if silently appended boiler-plate options result in `-lstdc++`
reappearing later in the linkage sequence, whether by itself or with
the surroundings:

```
-Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic
```

then the later appearance will simply be *redundant*, because the library has
already been linked.

So there is nothing peculiar about `gcc` that results in:

```
gcc file.cc -lstdc++ -static-libstdc++
```

producing a program in which `libstdc++` is *dynamically* linked. So does

```
g++ file.cc -lstdc++ -static-libstdc++
```

or indeed:

```
g++ file.cc -static-libstdc++ -lstdc++
```

because the generated linker commandline is of the form:

```
... file.o -lstdc++ ... -Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic ...
```

where `-Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic` is too late to make any difference.

Check it out:

**file.cc**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and link normally and inspect the dynamic dependencies with `ldd`:

```
$ g++ -o prog file.cc
$ ldd prog
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffede76a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f42fa74c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f42fa385000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f42fa07c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558ab42bc000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f42f9e65000)
```

`libstdc++.so` is present.

Now just with `-static-libstdc++`:

```
$ g++ -o prog file.cc -static-libstdc++
$ ldd prog
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff448d7000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe5f7c71000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe5f78aa000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556ebf272000)
```

`libstdc++.so` is absent.

And finally with `-static-libstdc++ -lstdc++`:

```
$ g++ -o prog file.cc -static-libstdc++ -lstdc++
$ ldd prog
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd12de9000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd5a1823000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd5a145c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd5a1153000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055bbe31c3000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd5a0f3c000)
```

`libstdc++.so` is back.

(This is Linux, of course, but you'll find the same thing on Windows).

So whether you drive your linkage with `g++` or `gcc`, the reason that

```
{gcc|g++} file.cc -lstdc++ ...
```

will result in `libstdc++` being dynamically linked is simply that

```
{gcc|g++} file.cc -lfoo ...
```

will cause `libfoo` to be dynamically linked, if it can be, regardless of
what `...` is, provided only that `...` does not contain the option `-static`.

Comment: This is a piece of comprehensive writing. I have a small note that when added as `LDFLAGS`, the flags is `-Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically not an answer, but a workaround for broken build systems.

I was working with a build system which for some very weird reason, used gcc instead of g++ to drive the build process, even for C++ objects. And I needed to have a binary with no dependency on anything other than glibc libraries. So, I ended up doing this:

```
$ cat <<EOF > gcc
#!/bin/bash
if [[ \$@ == *"-lstdc++"* ]]; then
    /full/path/to/g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ \$(echo \$@ | sed 's,-lstdc++,,g')
else
    /full/path/to/gcc -static-libgcc \$@
fi
EOF

$ chmod +x gcc

$ export PATH=$PWD:$PATH
```