# How do I get the static versions of the modules?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm working on a game in SFML. It runs correctly on my computer, but if I send it to another computer then when I try to run it I get errors about not being able to find libraries. I did some research and I found that the reason is because I was using dynamic libraries, and to get the program to work on its own I need the static libraries. But how do I get those? They aren't in my `sfml` folder. I tried doing more research but I can't find a way to build or download those libraries.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a distribution package which can be installed elsewhere? Then you could list your dependencies, and the system should install them as part of installing your game. Or in Windows, create an installer which include the DLL's needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried including the SFML DLLs, but I still got an error that it couldn't find `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` and `libstcdc++-6.dll`.

Comment: Yes, those are needed by the standard library. You can link that [statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488972/static-libstdc-works-on-g-but-not-on-pure-gcc) if you want.

Comment: @Botje I added `-static-libstdc++` when compiling but now it says even more files are missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you are using mingw compiler. You can add static arguments and try.

```
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

If this doesn't work try to search the two DLL files in your standard compiler path /bin folder and place them where your exe is located.

Comment: Adding static arguments didn't work, but I copied the DLL files and that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your sfml Src directory and look for the /bin folder. Copy the following DLLs to your game folder where your exe is located:

```
DLLs 

    sfml-graphics.dll
    sfml-window.dll
    sfml-audio.dll
    sfml-network.dll
    sfml-system.dll
```

On Linux, install libsfml-dev on target computer.

Comment: should also work if you add the  dll location to the PATH env variable, right?

Comment: Of course yes . But it would become  a mess if the person tries to run a software written in different SFML version.

Comment: I tried that, but I still got an error that it couldn't find `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` and `libstcdc++-6.dll`.